# Understanding Pointer Operations & CPU/Memory usage

Tags: go, pointers

I was talking to a colleague at work about whether or not it's more efficient to pass a pointer to a function and/or returning a pointer.

I put together some bench mark functions to test the different ways of doing this. The functions basically accept a variable, transform it and pass it back. We have 4 different ways of doing it:

1. Pass the variable in normally, create a new variable for the result of the transformation and pass back a copy of it
2. Pass the variable in normally, create a new variable for the result of the transformation, and pass back the memory address
3. Pass in a pointer to a variable, create a new variable for the result of the transformation and pass back a copy of that variable
4. Pass in a pointer to a variable, perform the transformation on the value of the pointer, nothing to pass back.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    myString string
}

func acceptParamReturnVariable(s MyStruct) MyStruct {
    ns := MyStruct{
        fmt.Sprintf("I'm quoting this: \"%s\"", s.myString),
    }
    return ns
}

func acceptParamReturnPointer(s MyStruct) *MyStruct {
    ns := MyStruct{
        fmt.Sprintf("I'm quoting this: \"%s\"", s.myString),
    }
    return &ns
}

func acceptPointerParamReturnVariable(s *MyStruct) MyStruct {
    ns := MyStruct{
        fmt.Sprintf("I'm quoting this: \"%s\"", s.myString),
    }
    return ns
}

func acceptPointerParamNoReturn(s *MyStruct) {
    s.myString = fmt.Sprintf("I'm quoting this: \"%s\"", s.myString)
}

func BenchmarkNormalParamReturnVariable(b *testing.B) {
    s := MyStruct{
        myString: "Hello World",
    }
    var ns MyStruct
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ns = acceptParamReturnVariable(s)
    }
    _ = ns
}

func BenchmarkNormalParamReturnPointer(b *testing.B) {
    s := MyStruct{
        myString: "Hello World",
    }
    var ns *MyStruct
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ns = acceptParamReturnPointer(s)
    }
    _ = ns
}

func BenchmarkPointerParamReturnVariable(b *testing.B) {
    s := MyStruct{
        myString: "Hello World",
    }
    var ns MyStruct
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ns = acceptPointerParamReturnVariable(&s)
    }
    _ = ns
}

func BenchmarkPointerParamNoReturn(b *testing.B) {
    s := MyStruct{
        myString: "Hello World",
    }
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        acceptPointerParamNoReturn(&s)
    }
    _ = s
}
```

I found the results rather surprising.

```
$ go test -run=XXXX -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: XXXX
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
BenchmarkNormalParamReturnVariable-16           10538138               103.3 ns/op            48 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkNormalParamReturnPointer-16             9526380               201.2 ns/op            64 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkPointerParamReturnVariable-16           7542066               147.0 ns/op            48 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkPointerParamNoReturn-16                   45897            119265 ns/op          924351 B/op          5 allocs/op
```

Before running this, I figured the most efficient way would have been the 4th test, since no new variables are being created in the scope of the function being called and only memory addressed are being passed around, however, it seems that the 4th one is the **least** efficient, taking the most time, as well as using the most memory too.

Could some one possible explain this to me, or provide me with some good reading links that explain this?

Comment: You aren’t measuring what you are interested in. Inspect the generated assembly code. This type of microbenchmark is _increadibly_ hard to get right.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to see which method is the more efficient way of doing things. After doing more reading, I understand now that when returning a pointer to a variable that is created inside a function, has that variable copied from the stack to the heap, once the function is finished and the frame removed from the stack. So while it might seem efficient in testing, long term it means more possible work for the GC, which could have it's own performance hit.

Comment: "Is there a better way for me to see which method is the more efficient way of doing things." No, because the question is malformed. This has basically _no_ impact on performance. A string is two words, a pointer one. Whether you pass or return one or two words doesn't matter the slightest in 99.9994% of all cases.

Comment: @Volker I get that there's very little difference between a string and a pointer to a string (specially a string of this size), but I was just using this as an example. The string could literally be anything, but I was trying to illustrate the concept. I kind of thought that was obvious?

Comment: The size of a `string` in Go is constant and always two words (the content is not part of the string variable). Degenerate cases make  bad examples. For _large_ structures there might be a difference. Large structures are uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarks you do don't answer the questions you ask. Microbenchmarking is proven to be extremely hard - not only in Go world but in general.

Coming back to the efficiency problem. Typically, passing a pointer to a function doesn't escape to the heap. And typically, returning a pointer from a function does escape to the heap. Typically is the key word here. You can't really say when the compiler allocates something on the stack and when on the heap. This is not a trivial problem. Really good and short explanation can be found [here](https://go.dev/doc/faq#stack_or_heap).

But if you need to know, you can ask. You can start by simply printing optimization decisions made by the compiler. You can do so by passing the `m` flag to the `go tool compile`.

```
go build -gcflags -m=1
```

If you pass integer greater than 1 you get more verbose output. If it doesn't give you the answer you need to optimize your program, then try [profiling](https://go.dev/blog/pprof). It goes much beyond the memory analysis.

In general, in your daily work do not bother with naive optimization decisions. Don't get too attached to the statements saying 'Typically...' because in real world, you never know. Always aim at the correctness optimization first. And then do the performance optimization only if you really need it and you proved that you need it. Do not guess, do not trust. Also, keep in mind, Go is changing so what we prove in one version, doesn't have to be true in the other.

Comment: Thanks, I recently learnt about the stack vs the heap, my only previous exposure to pointers is with C/C++ and this was like 20 years ago and I haven't really touched the subject since, so quite a bit has changed. Profiling (and the other optimization tools) is something I'll look into as we'll more than likely have to write up a guide for the other developers. It's good to know there's no right or wrong answer in this scenario.